# SQL Server varbinary clustered index lookups slow for certain ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, varbinary

At my work we currently have a table with 50 million rows that has an index on two Varbinary(16) columns which are ip_start and ip_end.

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ip_end] ASC,
    [ip_start] ASC
)
```

The first few rows in the table are  like this:

```
ip_start   ip_end      id
0x00000000  0x00000000  0
0x00000001  0x000000FF  1
0x00000100  0x00FFFFFF  2
0x01000000  0x010000FF  3
```

The query we use to find matches is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM dbo.ip_ranges WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE @lookup <= ip_end AND @lookup >= ip_start
```

When I lookup an ip like `0x00000002` it returns id 1 instantly, but if I search for a range that is in between a range like `0x000000000000001` it takes several seconds to return NULL. Shouldn't SQL Server understand that the varbinary index is ordered and therefore return quickly if there are no matches?

Is there a better way to query this with the expectation that some ip's will be between ranges or a better way to index the table so that misses don't cause such a large hit?

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't SQL Server understand that the varbinary index is ordered and therefore return quickly if there are no matches?

SQL Server understands that the index is *ordered*, but it does not understand that the ranges do not overlap.  This condition `@lookup >= ip_start` is true for a bunch of ip ranges (about half on average), and that is the performance that you see for a non-match.  The B-Tree index does not use the second key for an index lookup when the first key has an inequality.

Unfortunately, standard B-Tree indexes are not optimal for this type of search (inequalities along two dimensions).  An [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (which I originally learned as RD-tree) is better suited.  Those are used primarily for spatial indexes.

I think I have had success with a query such as this:

```
SELECT ir.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ir.*
      FROM dbo.ip_ranges ir
      WHERE @lookup >= ip_start
      ORDER BY ip_start
     ) ir
WHERE @lookup <= ir.ip_end ;
```

SQL Server should use an index for the subquery, quickly finding the first matching row.  You can then check separately if the end of the range is on this row.  This works because IP address ranges do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Create nonclustered index on ip_start with include column id

Or update clustered index on one column ip_start
and create nonclustered on ip_end with include column id